# Construct URL dynamically in "Send Message" step of WorkFlow

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

Tring to append response variable "hash" to a base url.

For example...

Base = "https://Google.com"
Variable = 'xyx123'

... then send message of (Base + variable) in URL format.

Is there a way to do this? I feel I have tried just about everything.

Thanks
[image]
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not currently possible to append Workflow Builder variables to a custom url. Happy to bring this as a feature request if you'd like!

Comment: Hi Sandra. If it would be possible to add the request, I would greatly appreciate it. Please let me know if there is somewhere I may be able to keep track of requests. Thanks